# How to add new light to existing 2-way switch

Tags: electrical, lighting, uk

- I currently have a 2 way light.
- I am working with the old Black and Red wires, not the current Blue and Brown. (I am in the UK.)
- There are 2 switches to this 1 light. Switch A and Switch B
- In the back of both switches, there are 2 wires coming down the walls. 1 wire is a twin and earth with the Black and Red, going to L2 and L1 respectively. And a second wire is a single core going to Common.

Constraints:

- I am unable to run a new cable from the existing light fitting to the new light fitting.
- I am only able to access the cables in the ceiling above Switch A.
- I am unable to run a new cable from any of the switches.

I have fitted the new light fitting and run a twin and earth from this new light fitting to where the Switch A wires are in the ceiling. (L1, L2 & Common)

1. Is it possible to add a second light to these switches?
2. If so, how do I do this with the constraints above?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question unless you tell us which switch is connected to the light.

Comment: @RobertChapin - I'm not sure how that matters. I don't think it can be done. To bring a new loop out of either switch [or try jumper into it halfway] would make a series connection going through both lamps, because the only neutral is in the ceiling above the existing lamp.

Comment: @Tetsujin , I might be able to get a neutral from the existing light

Comment: If you can get a cable across from the first rose, take a regular twin & earth. I've found a pict explaining it… lemme drop in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because UK lighting carries the power in the ceiling not in the walls [except for newer installations] then you can't jumper out of either switch, or the cabling in between, to do this - you have no neutral so the result would be a series connection through both lamps.

You need to be able to run parallel from the existing ceiling rose.

Google found this diagram on Pinterest, linked from https://flameport.com [though I can't find the relevant page.]

[image]

You can see from this that it doesn't matter how the switches are wired, one, two or three way, because the net sum of any/all those switches arrives back in the rose, ready to parallel off to any other rose. Your parallel takes the switched live plus a neutral [& earth] to the next lamp.
This is in new colours, but I'm sure it's simple to translate. There's usually only a 10% chance the installer actually put a brown or red sheath on the switched live, but you can tell by context, because all ceiling roses are like this 3, 3, 2 pattern for neutral, loop & line.

Because of the way UK lighting circuits work, you may already have a parallel matching the cable marked 'IN', unless this is the last fitting on that circuit. Leave that in situ [ignore it completely] as that will go off to another light in another room. They're all wired together, usually one circuit/fuse/breaker per floor, upstairs/downstairs.

*Late edit*
Of course, when you get to your new rose, you simply use the same terminals as the rose you came from, basically to each side of the new lamp - neutral & line [& earth]. You don't need anything else in there.